# Truncate long lines in emacs from command line argument

Tags: emacs

I know the command in the `.emacs` for long line truncation is:

```
(setq-default truncate-lines t)
```

or the keystroke:

```
M-x <RET> toggle-truncate-lines <RET>
```

but how do I pass these as parameters launching emacs from the shell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
emacs --eval '(setq-default truncate-lines t)'
```

Comment: Thank you! The quotes make all the difference it seems, I assume without them the shell tries to interpret them as a bash expression rather then a Lisp command passed to emacs?

Comment: This parameter didn't enable `truncate-line` on my end. Something does not allow to enable truncate line by default. @Gilles 'SO- stop being evil'

Comment: @alper Maybe something in your init file turns it off? Or maybe you're opening a file in a mode that turns it off? What exact commands are you using? Does it make a difference if you add `-q` to the command line?

Comment: In my  init file file, `(global-visual-line-mode 1)` was the issue, when I removed it, everything is solved.